# Javascript - how to set dynamic time interval form UTC time and show content

Tags: javascript, jquery

The goal is to show div to inform user for session expirations and offer to extend it before it expired. The session was set through back-end codes on each page load event and saved a cookie value with the next expire time in UTC.

Sample format in UTC Time : MM/dd/yyyy-HH:mm:ss

```
<div class="session-alert">
  <p>Your session is going to expire in a while. To keep the current session click "OK"</p>
  <button class="button button-session-ok">OK</button>
  <button class="button button-session-cancel">OK</button>
</div>
```

Now I wanted to show session-alert div 20 seconds before the next to expire time using JavaScript. How to convert the next expire time (UTC) to local and subtract 20 seconds form it and pass the time slap into an interval to show session-alert div? I wanted to use only core javascript or jquery no any third party JS or plugin.

```
var EXPIRE_COUNTDOWN_TIMER;

var nextExprireTime = new Date('05/20/2019-15:23:44');
var nextExprireTimeISO = nextExprireTime.toISOString();
var currLocalTime = new Date().toISOString();

var diff = (nextExprireTimeISO - currLocalTime) - 20 seconds;


EXPIRE_COUNTDOWN_TIMER = setInterval(function(){
  $('.session-alert').show();
}, diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: `toLocaleDateString`

> The **toLocaleDateString()** method returns a string with a language
>   sensitive representation of the date portion of this date. The new
>   locales and options arguments let applications specify the language
>   whose formatting conventions should be used and allow to customize the
>   behavior of the function. In older implementations, which ignore the
>   locales and options arguments, the locale used and the form of the
>   string returned are entirely implementation dependent.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

```js
var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
var today = new Date().toLocaleDateString('es-ES', options)
console.log(today)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the current eppocTime and epocTime for your UTC string,
then subtract currentEppocTime from the futureEpoch Time, if its 20 sec show the message

```
var currentEppocTime = new Date().getTime();
// your UTC string should be split into year,mon,day,hours,min,sec,milisec
var futureEppocTime = new Date(year,mon,day,hours,min,sec,milisec).getTime();

if (futureEppocTime - currentEppocTime <= 20) {
  // logic to show the message
}
```